# iReport 2.0.4: do string type parameters not work in SQL queries?

Tags: ireport

I'm working on a report in iReport 2.0.4 connecting to an Oracle database through `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` that returns a list of entries based on union membership.  The report takes a start date, end date, and union name as parameters.  The basic structure of the query is

```
select 
    ...
from
    ...
where
    union_opt_in_dt <= $P{EndDate} and
    union_opt_out_dt >= $P{StartDate} and
    union_name = $P{UnionName}
...
```

where `StartDate` and `EndDate` have type `java.lang.Date` and `UnionName` has type `java.lang.String`.

The problem is that, if I use the `UnionName` parameter and pass in the union name (example "AFSCME"), the query returns no data.  If I remove the `UnionName` parameter and hardcode the union name, as in

```
where
    union_opt_in_dt <= $P{EndDate} and
    union_opt_out_dt >= $P{StartDate} and
    union_name = 'AFSCME'
```

then I get the rows I expect for that union name.

So why do the date parameters work, but not the string parameter?  Is there a method I need to call on the string parameter (such as `.trim()`) to get it to work?

**UPDATE, FIXED**

Found an answer to a different question on another forum that fixes it; I have to do an immediate substitution (terminology?) of the parameter in the query, so it needs to be

```
where
    union_opt_in_dt <= $P{EndDate} and
    union_opt_out_dt >= $P{StartDate} and
    union_name = '$P!{UnionName}'
```

That works.  Not sure I understand the logic of it (as of a week and a half ago I'd never *heard* of Jasper Reports), but at least I can move forward.

**UPDATED UPDATE, *NOT* FIXED**

Okay, so the above solution isn't quite what I need; it only substitutes the default value, not necessarily what's passed in.  Argh.

Why do the dates work, but *not* the union name?  I've made sure that the value in the parameter exactly matches what's in the database, character for character.

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming the `UnionName` before passing.

Comment: I tried using `$P{UnionName}.trim()` in the query, but no joy; I get a syntax error when I run the report.

Comment: try trimming the parameter value of `UnionName` before handing it over to the report